# Get distance to analogous point on parallel line

Tags: vectors

[image]

Given three points $A, B, P $ and their coordinates $(A_x, A_y), (B_x, B_y), (P_x, P_y)$, I would like to find a fourth point $B'$ such that $BB'$ and $PB'$ are perpendicular and $PB'$ is parallel to $AB$.

Eventually I only want to find the length of $PB'$.

Is there a simpler way to compute this length than what I have come up with, which is arduously

- find the vector perpendicular to $\overrightarrow{AB}$
- use it to find the equation of the perpendicular through $B$
- find the intersection of that perpendicular with $P + \lambda\overrightarrow{AB}$
- calculate the magnitude $|B'_x - P_x, B'_y - P_y|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve this using [projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) of vectors.

Observe that the length that you want to find is equal to $\left| \mathrm{proj}_{\overrightarrow{AB}}\overrightarrow{PB}\right|$.

Recall that for any vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}\ne \mathbf{0}$, we have $\left|\mathrm{proj}_{\mathbf{b}}{\mathbf{a}}\right| = \frac{|\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}|}{|\mathbf{b}|}$.

Therefore, your desired length is
$$\begin{align*}
\left| \mathrm{proj}_{\overrightarrow{AB}}\overrightarrow{PB}\right| &= \frac{\left|\overrightarrow{PB}\cdot \overrightarrow{AB}\right|}{\left|\overrightarrow{AB}\right|}\\
&= \frac{\left|(B_x - P_x, B_y - P_y)\cdot (B_x - A_x, B_y - A_y)\right|}{\left|(B_x-A_x, B_y-A_y)\right|} \quad (\text{since } \overrightarrow{AB}=(B_x-A_x, B_y-A_y)\text{ and }\overrightarrow{PB}=(B_x-P_x,B_y-P_y))\\
&= \frac{\left|(B_x-P_x)(B_x-A_x)+(B_y-P_y)(B_y-A_y)\right|}{\sqrt{(B_x-A_x)^2 +(B_y-A_y)^2}}.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Have you kept $|...|$ on the top on purpose? Taking the absolute value there is important?

Comment: Yes, it is important we have the absolute value in the numerator, as otherwise the result may come out negative, but we want a non-negative answer as we want to calculate a length.